# Arrayadapter is not getting modified upon calling notifydatasetchanged()

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Guys I m using a simple listview. I have two activities one main and second one to add friend
In the second activity i m taking userid of friend in textbox and adding that row to the database and updating the arraylist.
When i comeback to the mainactivity i call the notifyDataSetChanged() in onResume() function and i also log the arraylist value. Arraylist is very fine and also the row is inserted in database but listview is not getting updated . I donno the problem plz help. Here is d code.

```
public class VayuActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    static boolean first_time=true;
    ListView friend_list;
    public static List<String> al;
    public  ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
    String dummyfriends[]={"prashant","monika","pramod","dhara"};
    public static MessengerDataSource mds;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
/*        if(first_time==true)
        {
            first_time=false;
            setContentView(R.layout.registration);
        }
        else */
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

        al=new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String i:dummyfriends)
            al.add(i);

        aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);

        friend_list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.friend_list);

        friend_list.setAdapter(aa);

        mds= new MessengerDataSource(getApplicationContext());

        mds.open();

        System.out.println("I m in oncreate");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        al=mds.getFriends();
        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();

        System.out.println("I m in on resume function");
        System.out.println("Value of arraylist in on resume fun"+al);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        System.out.println("I m in onpause function");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {


        MenuInflater mi=getMenuInflater();
        mi.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);

        return true;





    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.add_friend:
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Add Friend", 2000).show();
            Intent i=new Intent(VayuActivity.this,AddFriendActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case R.id.remove_friend:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Remove Friend", 2000).show();
            break;

        }


        return true;
    }
}



package com.pdd.vayu;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AddFriendActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    EditText et;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addfriend);

        et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.E_friendadd);

        Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.add_friend_button);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String userid=et.getText().toString();
        //VayuActivity.al.add(f);
        Friend f=new Friend();
        f.setUserid(userid);
        f.setFname("pratik");

        VayuActivity.mds.addFriend(f);
        VayuActivity.al=(ArrayList<String>) VayuActivity.mds.getFriends();
        System.out.println(VayuActivity.al);
        //VayuActivity.aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Database classes

```
package com.pdd.vayu;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class MessengerDataSource {

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MyDatabaseHelper mydbh;

    public static String USER_ID="userid";
    public static String F_NAME="fname";
    public static String CHAT_COUNT="chat_count";

    public static String M_TEXT="mtext";
    public static String SENDER="sender";
    public static String RECEIVER="receiver";
    public static String M_TYPE="type";



    public MessengerDataSource(Context c)
    {
        mydbh=new MyDatabaseHelper(c);
    }

    public void open()
    {
        try
        {
            database=mydbh.getWritableDatabase();   
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        mydbh.close();
    }

    public void addFriend(Friend f)

    {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(USER_ID,f.getUserid());
        cv.put(F_NAME, f.getFname());
        cv.put(CHAT_COUNT, f.getChat_count());

        try
        {
            database.insert(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_FRIEND, null, cv);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error while inserting  "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    }

    public void addMessage(Message m)

    {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(M_TEXT, m.getText());
        cv.put(SENDER,m.getSender());
        cv.put(RECEIVER,m.getReceiver());
        cv.put(M_TYPE, m.getType());


        database.insert(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_MESSAGE, null, cv);
    }

    public void deleteFriend(String fname)
    {
        database.delete(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_FRIEND,F_NAME+"="+fname , null);

    }

    public void deleteMessage(String text)

    {
        database.delete(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_FRIEND,M_TEXT+"="+text , null);
    }

    public List<String> getFriends()

    {
        List<String> friends= new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor c=null;
        try
        {
        c=database.query(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_FRIEND, new String[]{F_NAME}, null, null, null, null,CHAT_COUNT);
        }
        catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Error while retrieving frnds list"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                String friend=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(F_NAME));
                friends.add(friend);
            }
            while(c.moveToNext());
        }




        return friends;
    }

    public List<String> getMessages(String from)

    {
        List<String> messages= new ArrayList<String>();

        String where=SENDER+"="+from;

        Cursor c=database.query(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_MESSAGE, new String[]{M_TEXT},where , null, null, null,null);

        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                String message=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(M_TEXT));
                messages.add(message);
            }
            while(c.moveToNext());
        }


        return messages;
    }




}
```

Database Helper

```
package com.pdd.vayu;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public static String TABLE_FRIEND="friend";

    public static String TABLE_MESSAGE="message";

    public static String CREATE_FRIEND="create table if not exists "+ 
    TABLE_FRIEND+" (userid varchar primary key,fname varchar,chat_count int);";

    public static String CREATE_MESSAGE="create table if not exists "+
    TABLE_MESSAGE+"(mid integer primary key autoincrement," +
    "mtext varchar," +"sender varchar , receiver varchar , type varchar)";

    //public static String TABLE_FRIENDS="friends";

    public static String DB_NAME="MessengerDB.db";

    Context context;


    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL(CREATE_FRIEND);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_MESSAGE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Pls help

Comment: you have to set a1 data again in arrayadpter in onresume().

Comment: i did tat only in this line al=mds.getFriends();

Comment: In List arrayadpter not refresh if its changed data not reinsert in adpter so try it like oncreate method  aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);

Comment: I didnt understant . Can u pls elaborate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For notifyDataSetChanged() to work, you must add the object to the ArrayAdapter itself using it's add/remove methods and not the actual list.

Your onResume should look something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    //al=mds.getFriends();
    aa.clear();
    aa.addAll(mds.getFriends());
    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();

    System.out.println("I m in on resume function");
    System.out.println("Value of arraylist in on resume fun"+al);
}
```

The ArrayAdapter creates a copy of the list when initiated, so when calling notifyDataSetChanged it only looks in it's own copy, not the source list.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try notifyDataSetChanged() method like this

Sometime it not load data when you not load new data in adpter so before call this you have to load data in arrayadpter in onresume() method instead onCreate().

```
public void refresh()
    {

        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                ((EfficentAdapter)list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); 
                }           
        }, 100);

    }
```